# Issues in slideout control UI

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am bit new to CSS/bootstrap style programming.
I am trying to create a SlideOut control. Please refer the working code in [URL](http://fiddle.jshell.net/snkrishnan1/efhfos7L/2/) .

I am facing some issues as listed below

1. I am not able to get the curve on the left side of the button i.e. Top-Left and Bottom-Left (Please refer snapshot)[image]
2. I want to increase the size of the Feedback area i.e. want to have the height and width as 500px each. But When I try chaning it in the CSS #slideout_inner, the slide out doesn't happen properly/smoothly.

I want to implement this slideout control using HTML and CSS/bootstrap only and don't want to use JQuery in it.
Can anyone please help me with this issues?

Space getting added inbetween the Button and the innerarea, [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Border:**

turn your border radius around

It should be like this

```
border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;

/* here is the pattern */
border-radius: top-right top-left bottom-left bottom-right
```

**Sizing:**

You have to change the sizing in 3 places

```
#slideout:hover {
  right: here;
}

#slideout_inner textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  width: here;
  height: 200px;
}

#slideout_inner textarea {
  width: here;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
#slideout {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #6DAD53;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#slideout_inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: -550px;
  background: #6DAD53;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 130px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
#slideout_inner textarea {
  width: 490px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#slideout:hover {
  right: 550px;
}
#slideout:hover #slideout_inner {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideout">
  <img src="http://img.usabilitypost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/css_slideout/feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
  <div id="slideout_inner">
    <form>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Post feedback">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Curves are looking fine, How do I increase the width and Height of the feedback area?

Comment: @Krishnan you have to change the size in 3 places but when you do that it works fine.

Comment: tried in #slideout_inner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: -250px;
  background: #6DAD53;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 400px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}   It totally changes the entire look and smoothness and doesn't slide-in. what is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: apart from #slideout_inner, what are the other 2 places where I need to change it?

Comment: @Krishnan I've amended my answer, I'm guessing this is just code you found somewhere as opposed to something you wrote yourself.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine in JSfiddle. I tried copying the same styles in my actual project. It works as expected apart from a single issue as mentioned in the new snapshot i have attached. I am getting some space between the slideout button and the inner area, any ideas why is it causing this issue?

Comment: @Krishnan means your #slideout:hover right number isn't correct.